# How to know if the JVM is currently doing GC ?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, load-balancing

I have a use case, where I need to stop requests being sent to a java restful service, if the JVM of the service is currently doing a GC. How/which API can hep me to find this ?

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: You can ping the service with a simple request and if it doesn't respond, it's busy. If you want to do this predicatively, you could have the service stream a heartbeat to the load balancer and if this pauses, you assume it's busy.

Comment: Yup, I agree that will work. But I was exploring if I can find a cleaner approach like my JMX/monitoring agent can tell my load balancer that the JVM is gona start its GC. So dont send any request until I say its completed.

Comment: @PeterLawrey interesting, but I hoped there is an API call of some kind in `javax.management` may be that could tell you if at least a major GC is in progress now

Comment: If stop-the-world GC is in progress - then JMX or any other Java API will not work, since it will be also affected by GC. If a concurrent GC is in progress - you should not care, since application will be still able to respond .

Comment: @Eugene When the GC performs a stop the world collection, almost all functionality stops as well. `jstat` uses a call with is concurrent with the GC. You could find out what call it uses to do this or run the tool to see when a JVM is about to perform a GC.

Comment: This is just another application of the check-then-act anti-pattern. After you’ve detected that there is no garbage collection at the moment, what prevents a garbage collection from starting right when you started submitting your request?

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to monitor GC, but the only difference is how the GC operation information is shown. GC is done by JVM, and since the GC monitoring tools disclose the GC information provided by JVM, you will get the same results no matter how you monitor GC.

The GC monitoring methods can be separated into **CUI** and **GUI** depending on the access interface. The typical CUI GC monitoring method involves using a separate CUI application called "jstat", or selecting a JVM option called "verbosegc" when running JVM.

**jstat** is a monitoring tool in HotSpot JVM. Other monitoring tools for HotSpot JVM are jps and jstatd. Sometimes, you need all three tools to monitor a Java application.

-**verbosegc** is one of the JVM options specified when running a Java application. While jstat can monitor any JVM application that has not specified any options, -verbosegc needs to be specified in the beginning, so it could be seen as an unnecessary option (since jstat can be used instead).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this by using visualVM and it's API. The visual vm is the visualization of the GC process. But it has it's own API as well.
[Visual VM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html)

Comment: I am sorry can you elaborate more, cause it sound interesting when you say VisualVm has its own API. From my knowledge I see the VisualVM as a client basically  uses the JMX and its MBeans to get its information, by pooling I suppose. But how can a third app/client use this to do something when lets say a Major GC happens ? Reference to any artical will also be useful.

Comment: I saw they have their own API you need to search for it. I havent tried it yet